# NativeScript: how to use android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat on Android 4

Tags: nativescript

Is there a good way to use Material AppCompat Switch on Android 4? If so, please give an example of usage in NativeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little research and found that there is no easy way to use Material design for Switch with version lower then 5.
Switch component is available from  API v7 as it has been described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html). However you could change some basic style properties by accessing android property. I am attaching sample code:

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="load">
  <StackLayout>
  <Switch id="test" checked="{{ checked }}" class="style"   />

  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**main-page.js**

```
function load(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var tmpswitch = page.getViewById("test");
    tmpswitch.android.setShowText(false);
    tmpswitch.android.setSwitchMinWidth(15);
}
exports.load = load;
```